# Metaclasses in Python: a couple of questions to clarify

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

After crashing with metaclasses i delved into the topic of metaprogramming in Python and I have a couple of questions that are, imho, not clearly anwered in available docs.

1. When using both `__new__` and `__init__` in a metaclass, their arguments must be defined the same?
2. What's most efficient way to define class `__init__` in a metaclass?
3. Is there any way to refer to class instance (normally *self*) in a metaclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: The `__init__` and `__new__` of *any* class have to accept the same arguments, because they would be called with the same arguments. It's common for `__new__` to take more arguments that it ignores (e.g. `object.__new__` takes any arguments and it ignores them) so that `__new__` doesn't have to be overridden during inheritance, but you usually only do that when you have no `__new__` at all.

This isn't a problem here, because as it was stated, metaclasses are always called with the same set of arguments always so you can't run into trouble. With the arguments at least. But if you're modifying the arguments that are passed to the parent class, you need to modify them in both.

For 2: You usually don't define the class `__init__` in a metaclass. You can write a wrapper and replace the `__init__` of the class in either `__new__` or `__init__` of the metaclass, or you can redefine the `__call__` on the metaclass. The former would act weirdly if you use inheritance.

```
import functools

class A(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        r = super(A, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "%s was instantiated" % (cls.__name__, )
        print "the new instance is %r" % (r, )
        return r


class B(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(B, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        if '__init__' not in dct:
            return
        old_init = dct['__init__']
        @functools.wraps(old_init)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            old_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print "%s (%s) was instantiated" % (type(self).__name__, cls.__name__)
            print "the new instance is %r" % (self, )
        cls.__init__ = __init__


class T1:
    __metaclass__ = A

class T2:
    __metaclass__ = B
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

class T3(T2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(T3, self).__init__()
```

And the result from calling it:

```
>>> T1()
T1 was instantiated
the new instance is <__main__.T1 object at 0x7f502c104290>
<__main__.T1 object at 0x7f502c104290>
>>> T2()
T2 (T2) was instantiated
the new instance is <__main__.T2 object at 0x7f502c0f7ed0>
<__main__.T2 object at 0x7f502c0f7ed0>
>>> T3()
T3 (T2) was instantiated
the new instance is <__main__.T3 object at 0x7f502c104290>
T3 (T3) was instantiated
the new instance is <__main__.T3 object at 0x7f502c104290>
<__main__.T3 object at 0x7f502c104290>
```

For 3: Yes, from `__call__` as shown above.

Comment: If it's so atypical, then what's the recommended way when I need to dynamically create class along with it's `__init__`? (deliberately not calling this "constructor" since it matters in metaprogramming context)

Comment: To dynamically create classes, you'd use a class factory (a function that returns a class probably defined in its body). If you want to programatically modify the statically defined classes, you'd use a class decorator. A metaclass can be used to do both things, but it's usually much more than you want.

Answer (score 2):

1. *When using both `__new__` and `__init__`
   in a metaclass, their arguments must
   be defined the same?*

   I think [Alex Martelli](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-November/057906.html) explains
   it most succinctly:

   ```
   class Name(Base1,Base2): <<body>>
       __metaclass__==suitable_metaclass
   ```

   means

   ```
   Name = suitable_metaclass('Name', (Base1,Base2), <<dict-built-by-body>>)
   ```

   So stop thinking about
   suitable_metaclass as a metaclass
   for a moment and just regard it as a
   class. Whenever you see

   ```
   suitable_metaclass('Name', (Base1,Base2), <<dict-built-by-body>>)
   ```

   it tells you that
   suitable_metaclass's `__new__`
   method must have a signature
   something like

   ```
   def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
   ```

   and a `__init__` method like

   ```
   def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
   ```

   So the signatures are not exactly the same, but they differ only in the first argument.
2. *What's most efficient way to define
   class `__init__` in a metaclass?*

   What do you mean by efficient? It is
   not necessary to define the `__init__`
   unless you want to.
3. *Is there any way to refer to class
   instance (normally self) in a
   metaclass?*

   No, and you should not need to.
   Anything that depends on the class
   instance should be dealt with in the
   class definition, rather than in the
   metaclass.

Comment: I mean what's most elegant, clear, fastest or simply your favourite way when there is nevertheless a need to define some initial routines (that is, actual "work" as opposed to simply passing attributes) in resulting class.

Comment: Why don't you provide an example of how you currently do it?

Comment: @Red: I think `def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct)` is pretty standard. There aren't that many choices, except for minor variations in variable names, such as `klass` for `cls`, or `clsdict` for `dct`, etc.